# Swift 4 - sizeForItemAt on UICollectionView is not resizing the entire cell content

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to dynamically resize a CollectionView cell based using the height of the CollectionView set by Autolayout. The cell has an ImageView and a Label, but only the ImageView is being resized.

[image: Result on screen]

My code looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.templateCollectionView.frame.height * 5 / 6, height: self.templateCollectionView.frame.height * 5 / 6)
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Changing the cell size could well be changing the label size, but the font size wouldn’t change. Have you checked the label dimensions after the change in size?

Comment: What are the constraints you set in your cell?

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I had the UIImageView constraint set improperly so it was growing beyond what I expected for the cell size.